# calendar control for blank windows 8 application using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, calendar

Is it possible to create some sort of "pop up calendar" in a Windows Application (VB.net). Something similar to AjaxCalendarControl.

Or is it possible to add the same Ajax control in vb.net as we do for C#.net?
or any other way to get a calendar control for the same.

Comment: do you mean something like the [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes. I meant the same.